# AdminLTE Integration with React and JQuery not working until I refresh a few times

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm working on web application using React and trying to integrate AdminLTE theme to it. The problem is when the page is loaded and I click on the side menu to expand the submenu until I refresh the page for a few times.

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- icheck bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/mine.css">
    <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/mine.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/toastr.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/wordpress-admin.css">

    <script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>    


    <title>KVC Computer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->

    <script src="dist/js/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/toastr.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>  
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the page I've talked about.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAiN5.jpg)

I missed something or I did something wrong?
Any advices? Please...

Thank you